# Unable to Debug Projects in Solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, vsto

I have an issue with debugging library projects in a VS.NET 2013 VSTO solution. Both used to work and for some reason when I run the project in a debug session the Modules window shows that the problematic (non-debuggable) assemblies are being loaded from a different path (D:\Work\Path\To\Source\Repo).

This is a Word addin so the other modules are loaded in the c:\users\myname\appdata\local\ dir. The problem libraries are loading from the actual directory where the source lives on disk (D:). There are a total of five projects in the solution and all load from the same spot as the Word addin assembly and are debuggable. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue...  seen many of these types of questions all over the net...  make sure that if you're debugging a VSTO addin or similar app that you do not manually load assemblies yourself - this screws up the modules for the vs.net debugger and renders satellite assemblies non-debuggable.  Here is a sample of the offending code:

```
            var assemblyInfo = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            var uriCodeBase = new Uri(assemblyInfo.CodeBase);
            var clickOnceLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(uriCodeBase.LocalPath);
            // find all simple injector packages
            var packages = (from file in new DirectoryInfo(clickOnceLocation).GetFiles()
                            where file.Extension == ".dll" && file.Name.ToLowerInvariant() != "myaddin.core.dll" &&
                            file.Name.StartsWith("MyAddin")
                            select Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName)).ToList();
```

Comment: This was happening for DI purposes to find configuration packages